# recently i updated my expo-cli to version 3.13.1 and all of a sudden the applications are not working

Tags: react-native, expo

after updating expo-cli to 3.13.1 , when i start the application i get errors .
on npm start
     - **Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version: - react-native-safe-area-context - expected version range: 0.6.0 - actual version installed: ^0.7.3 Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]**

if i install react-native-safe-area-context@0.6.0 , it gives the following error 
**Unable to resolve "./InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx**

before updating it was working fine .

Comment: Are you installing it with npm or with expo?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're installing it with npm. You should install it with Expo:

```
expo install react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
`expo doctor --fix-dependencies`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: "If you are working on a managed app and the build error is a native error rather than a JavaScript error, this is likely due to a config plugin or a dependency in your project. Keep an eye out in the logs for any new packages that you've added since your previous successful build. Run expo doctor to determine that the versions of Expo SDK dependencies in your project are compatible with your Expo SDK version." `https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/`